# Libraries in the pom.xml are not available at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I spent the last three days struggling with this issue, so may as well post the answer so it will save someone's time.

I created a new Maven project, added some dependencies from my local repository to its pom, and wrote code to use classes from within those jars.

I also tried removing the dependencies and adding the jars manually, via Project Properties - Java Build Path - Libraries - Add External JARs...

Either way, at runtime I would get a ClassNotFoundException or a NoClassDefFoundException, stating that the definition of the class I was trying to access could not be found. Those classes could seemingly be found at compile time - no errors in the project, and I could view the class definition by Ctrl+clicking its name.

The only workaround I had found was to add the libraries to my tomcat/lib directory.

Comment: This can happen often when deploying a maven webapp in a webserver that's managed by the IDE (tomcat within Eclipse). Maven/Eclipse then fails to update the dependencies in ``WEB-INF/lib/`` in the deployed webapp.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, my local Maven repository was corrupt.

I navigated to my C:\users\.m2 directory and renamed the "repository" directory to "oldrepository". I then attempted a "clean install" of my project - took a while for Maven to download all the jars again, but when that was done everything worked seamlessly.

I don't know how much of the repository was corrupt, and if it was overkill to delete the whole thing, but it worked for me.

Hope this helps someone in the future.